# XtraTreeList - How can I reset the value of Unbound Boolean Cell to Indeterminate?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtratreelist

I have an XtraTreeList with an UnboundColumn of type Boolean, i.e.:

```
column.UnboundType = DevExpress.XtraTreeList.Data.UnboundColumnType.Boolean;
```

Initially, all CheckEdits are displayed 'grayed', in the Indeterminate State, and their value is Null.

Is there any way I can reset the values of particular check boxes to this Indeterminate state?

I have tried:

```
treeListNode[columnID] = null;
```

but an Error Message Box pops up, with the message: "Null object cannot be converted to a value type."

Also:

```
treeListNode[columnID] = DefaultBoolean.Default;
```

and:

```
treeListNode[columnID] = CheckState.Indeterminate;
```

but both set the cell's value to True.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this still helps you but the other approach that you can try is setting the unbound column type to object and later restoring it.

```
foreach (var column in treeListNode.Columns)
{
    var tc= column as TreeListColumn;
    if (tc!= null && tc.Name == columnID)
    {
        var originalType = tc.UnboundType;
        tc.UnboundType = UnboundColumnType.Object;
        treeListNode[columnID] = null;                             
        tc.UnboundType = originalType;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't check this out because I'm not working on the project anymore, and I don't personally have the DevExpress software. Still, thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
treeListNode[columnID] = DBNull.Value
```

but I am not sure it works, eventually we have to set the state of the CheckEdit manually.

Comment: Thank you for input. However, that doesn't work either. An Error MessageBox shows up, with the message: "Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types."
So far, the only way I've been able to work around is to delete the entire column and recreate it.